# How to build a Chinese GUI with wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I am wondering how can I build a Simplified Chinese GUI with wxWidgets? Can anyone point a direction that I can look into.

Comment: What part of this are you struggling with? What has been tried. Any errors?

Comment: What does it mean? A Chinese GUI? Just replace all English words by Chinese by enabling UTF8

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, because I don't know where to start. How can I enabling UTF8? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you are running on MSWindows and using wxWidgets v2.9 ( you don't say, which makes it hard to answer your question ) then you should be aware that windows and wxWidgets use UTF16 internally.  So, therefore, should you.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

[image]

For this kind of work, I use Poedit ( http://www.poedit.net/ )

Poedit is cross-platform gettext catalogs (.po files) editor. It is built with wxWidgets toolkit and can run on any platform supported by it (although it was only tested on Unix with GTK+ and Windows). It aims to provide more convenient approach to editing catalogs than launching vi and editing the file by hand.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [tutorial](http://wxwidgets.info/wxtranslation/) about enabling support of multiple languages in wxWidgets applications. And [video](http://wxwidgets.info/localization_video/).